# How to add Eclipse-Plugin Jars comfortably to a project?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar

After installing a Eclipse Plugin (namely Zest), I was wondering how to add the Jar's libraries to my Java project.

Of course, I can add them under my built path settings with "add external JARs" and search my program directories for the plugin folder and the Jar's.

But isn't there a more comfortable way ? I was thinking of some project menu in Eclipse to say  "add all libraries from plugin XYZ" ?

Comment: Are you writing an Eclipse plugin? If so, a plain Java project and managing dependencies via "add external JARs" is definitely not going to work.

Comment: No, just a regular Java Project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven to manage libraries (very comfortable)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I hoped for a native Eclipse solution, but I will consider using maven.